# how to show &lt;html&gt; in textarea

Tags: html

In textarea, I load text from database and then show in textarea. I have a problem, textarea not show `&lt;` and `&gt;`. It has been changed to < and > .

```
<textarea>&gt;html&gt;</textarea>
```

in textarea , change to  . I want to show `&lt;html&gt;` , how to make it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape the `&` by using `&amp;`.

Change this:

```
<textarea>&lt;html&gt;</textarea>
```

To this:

```
<textarea>&amp;lt;html&amp;gt;</textarea>
```

If you're using PHP you can automatically do this with `htmlspecialchars()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the Entity Number. It depends on the page character set. For ISO-8859-1 you would do  "&#60(semicolon)" and "&#62(semicolon)". replace the "(semicolon)" part with ; ... This just shows that this page supports it too :)

For a complete list view [HTML ISO-8859-1 Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)