# How to prevent HTML textarea from converting special symbols such as &gt;?

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML `<textarea>` environment converts character sequences representing special symbols such as

```
&gt;
```

into the according symbol:

```
>
```

However, I am trying to build a code editor which is supposed to take user inputs character by character in a verbatim way. The problem is that if a user types `&gt;` into the editor and compiles the code, the `<textarea>`is reloaded and during this process the characters are converted.

Here is an MWE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>  

<body>
    <textarea>
        &lsquo;
        &rsquo;
        &sbquo;
        &ldquo;
        &rdquo;
        &bdquo;
        &dagger;
        &Dagger;
    </textarea>
</html>
```

All the stuff within the textarea editor is converted when the page is loaded.

Escaping all the `&` symbols may be an option (as suggested here: [how to show &lt;html&gt; in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003375/how-to-show-lthtmlgt-in-textarea)), but it feels as if it wasn't the really correct thing to do. (Wouldn't I have to consider much more special cases such as HTML tags etc.??)

Is there a "recommended" way to implement code editors in HTML?

I tried [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/), but the problem remains there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Escaping all the & symbols may be an option but it feels as if it wasn't the really correct thing to do.

It is *absolutely* the correct thing to do

> Wouldn't I have to consider much more special cases such as HTML tags etc.??

Yes.

As with any other piece of *text* that you want to insert into an HTML document, characters in that text which have special meaning in HTML should be converted to HTML first.

Happily, you only have to worry about the *characters* and not special case anything as complicated as a tag.

---

How you do it depends on how you are generating your HTML.

In template toolkit:

```
<textarea>[% myData | html %]</textarea>
```

In PHP:

```
<textarea><?php echo htmlspecialchars($myData, ENT_QUOTES); ?></textarea>
```

Comment: Ok, I can do that easily. I just wasn't sure if it's the right way. I'm using Java to create the HTML - there should be predefined methods to escape special symbols. Already found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265282/recommended-method-for-escaping-html-in-java

Answer (score 1):

As you say, escaping the `&` is the best option. It is correct, according to the fact that you want to display `&gt;`. That way, it will be directly properly understood.