# Prevent automatic HTML special character encoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a signature creator where you have some input fields and it generates an html page which you can use in Outlook as a signature. The problem is when there are special characters in 1 of the input fields, it will display some random characters ( e.g. é becomes Ã© ). I've got some code to encode the special characters to html safe characters, but these get automatically converted back when injected in the html page. Is there a way to get the encoded characters into the html?

Here's jsfiddle of my problem (Open console in browser to view results):
https://jsfiddle.net/hdywwwf4/

This is what I want:

```
<h2 id="tester">&eacute;&eacute;&eacute;</h2>
```

This is what I get:

```
<h2 id="tester">ééé</h2>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show &lt;html&gt; in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003375/how-to-show-lthtmlgt-in-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

Try using .innerText() to set the h2 content instead of .innerHTML()
This results in following element:

```
<h2 id="tester">&amp;eacute;&amp;eacute;&amp;eacute; </h2>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hdywwwf4/3/

Comment: This solution also worked but I discovered that I just needed to add following meta-tag to head of the signature page: <meta charset="UTF-8">
This way outlook won't freak out on the special characters and I don't need to find a workaround.
Thanks for your response!